# How to check wheather Datadog agent is installed in UNIX box?

Tags: datadog

Just wanted to check weather Datadog agent is installed in UNIX box or not. I ran a command **sudo /etc/init.d/datadog-agent status** but got below output
**sudo: /etc/init.d/datadog-agent: command not found**

Please advice

Comment: Can you add to your question 1. the OS/version of the box you are running this on and 2. how you installed the agent?

Comment: thanks for quick reply, i didn't install the agent it was present in one of the unix env. Actually its a docker image. I just wanted to know is my agent installed correctly

Answer (score 1):

For the container agent, you'll want to run `sudo docker exec -it dd-agent /etc/init.d/datadog-agent status` from your unix based box. If, however, you are using the alpine image the command is: `docker exec -it dd-agent /opt/datadog-agent/bin/agent status` (different path). More here in this KB from Datadog: https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/203764635-Agent-Status-and-Information